# strtotime back and forward onemonth is wrong

Tags: php, timezone, strtotime

How can i solve this problem?

I set for example (31.10.2013),
but script returns (01.11.2013)

```
echo $currentDate = "2013-10-31";     
echo date("Y-m-D",strtotime("+1 month",strtotime("-1 month",strtotime($currentDate))));

Output is:
2013-10-31
2013-11-01
```

Comment: you can't do that in 1 single action.. You need to write 2 seperate ones, 1 for the -1 month and 1 for the +1 month...

Comment: @Dieter well, OP actually can. I confirm, that `DateTime` class has same behaviour.

Comment: If you're adding one month to the 31st October, you're going to get the 1st December returned - there is no 31st November, so it rolls over to the next day. Date arithmetic like this isn't as easy as you'd think.

Comment: I would also strongly suggest using DateTime objects, even though that doesn't solve your immediate problem.

Comment: @andrewsi OP is substracting first: http://3v4l.org/XONfX

Comment: @CORRUPT - my point still stands. It's because performing arithmetic with dates doesn't work in the way it looks like it should.

Comment: @andrewsi more interesting is why PHP makes 1st of october from 31th of october while substracting one month. Shouldn't it be 30th of september ?

Comment: @CORRUPT - but what's 'a month'? I'd guess that subtracting a month from the 31st October tries to return 31st September, and since there isn't one, it rolls over to the 1st October.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works as it should in your code. The problem is there is only 30 days in november. So when you add 1 to the month the date changes to 11-31-2013, which doesn't exist so it rolls to 12-1-2013. Then you are subtracting a month, which return 11-1-2013. I hope this clears up your issue.